# Comments limitations and nested comments

Tags: youtube-api

I used java Youtube api to extract comments from one video and i have some problem. In fact, i want to download all the comments related to one specific video in one go. Is it possible to do so? What appears to me is, there is limitation of 25 comments. Can you tell me the property that must be changed to overcome this limit please ?

Another issue please:  I have also a problem to Identify comments that are replies to other  comments, it's possible to check that.

I use Eclipse Editor.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the YouTube API feeds return pages with 25 entries each. The proper way to handling paging using the Java client library is explained at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Pagination

Comments that are in response to another comment will have a

`<link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#in-reply-to" ...>`

as explained at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Retrieve_comments

Comment: thank you very much ! i don't succeed to fix the identifier for each comment ! Can you help me please